# Get the redis keys with size in azure redis console

Tags: azure, redis, node-redis, azure-redis-cache, redis-cli

I m using azure redis cache and want to get the list of redis keys with its size.
Which command will work on the azure redis console ?

Comment: Please edit your question and include what commands have you tried and the issues you are running with them.

Comment: @GauravMantri i m using keys * to get the list of all keys, but not sure what command will use to get the size of the listed keys.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.